# Intro js missed focus on modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, intro.js

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to implement introJs, when IntroJs starts it misses the focus on the first step. When you go back from step one to step two it looks OK. I have tried to change the position from fixed to absolute, it doesn't work either.

[IntroJs modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrcxi.png).

Comment: Are you initiating `intoJs` after `modal`?

Comment: thanks that's solved my problem!